# Warning: Unable to set Geometry error - pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

**File: telephone_calls.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'C:\Users\chris\My Projects\papinhio-player\ui/menu-4/create/telephone-calls.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.7
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1102, 239)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1102, 239))
        Dialog.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1102, 239))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/telephone.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"    font-weight:bold;\n"
"    color:green;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.add_call_details_const = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.add_call_details_const.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 29))
        self.add_call_details_const.setObjectName("add_call_details_const")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.add_call_details_const)
        self.add_call_details_dynamic = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.add_call_details_dynamic.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 29))
        self.add_call_details_dynamic.setObjectName("add_call_details_dynamic")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.add_call_details_dynamic)
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollArea.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea#scrollArea{\n"
"    border:1px solid #ABABAB;\n"
"    background:transparent;\n"
"}")
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1082, 56))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setStyleSheet("QWidget#scrollAreaWidgetContents{\n"
"    background:rgb(229, 240, 27);\n"
"}")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(9, 9, 9, 9)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.details_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.details_frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.details_frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.details_frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame#details_frame{\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    /*image: url(:/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/telephone-calls-background.png);*/\n"
"}")
        self.details_frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.details_frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.details_frame.setObjectName("details_frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.details_frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.details_frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("QFrame{border:none;}")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(7)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.save.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.save.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.save.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 29))
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/rest-windows/assets/images/rest-windows/save.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.save.setIcon(icon1)
        self.save.setObjectName("save")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.save)
        self.cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.cancel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 29))
        self.cancel.setObjectName("cancel")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.cancel)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Στοιχεία ηχητικών κλήσεων"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Σημείωση 1: Μπορείτε να είσαγετε όσες ηχητικές κλήσεις θέλετε (μέχρι 3 ταυτόχρονα) για μία ζωντανή εκπομπή.\n"
"Σημείωση 2: Η επιλογή του ακριβούς χρονικού διαστήματος (κάθε ηχητικής κλήσης θα γίνει στην συνέχεια στην καρτέλα 5.\n"
"Σημείωση 3: Μία ηχητική κλήση μπορεί να έχει σταθερά στοιχεία κατά τις επαναλήψεις της προγραμματισμένης μετάδοσης αλλά μπορεί και να μην έχει σταθερά στοιχεία (ειδοποίηση 10 λεπτά πριν την έναρξη της προγραμματισμένης μετάδοσης με σκοπό την επιλογή των στοιχείων των ηχητικών κλήσεων)."))
        self.add_call_details_const.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Προσθήκη δεδομένων και άλλης ηχητικής κλήσης (με σταθερά στοιχεία (όνομα -επώνυμο - διάρκεια))"))
        self.add_call_details_dynamic.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Προσθήκη δεδομένων και άλλης ηχητικής κλήσης (με μή σταθερά στοιχεία (όνομα -επώνυμο - διάρκεια))"))
        self.save.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Αποθήκευση"))
        self.cancel.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Ακύρωση"))
```

**File: run_me.py**

```py
import telephone_calls
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import copy
import traceback


class Run_me:

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.live_ip_calls = []
        
            self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
            self.Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
            self.ui = telephone_calls.Ui_Dialog()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)
            self.Dialog.show()

            
            self.label_height = self.ui.label.size().height()
            
            #add_call_details const click event
            self.ui.add_call_details_const.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.on_add_call_details_const_click(state))
            
            #add_call_details dynamic click event
            self.ui.add_call_details_dynamic.clicked.connect(lambda state:self.on_add_call_details_dynamic_click(state))

            self.ui.save.setEnabled(False)
            
            #cancel click event
            self.ui.cancel.setEnabled(False)
            
            self.resize_the_Dialog()
            
            self.Dialog.closeEvent = lambda event:self.closeEvent(event)

            sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)

    #add_call_details const click event
    def on_add_call_details_const_click(self,state):
        try:
            ip_call_item = {}
            
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"] = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Dialog)
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
            "    border:1px solid #ABABAB;background-color:#EFEFEF;\n"
            "}")
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            ip_call_item["gridLayout"] = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            ip_call_item["ip_call_label"] = QtWidgets.QLabel(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            ip_call_item["ip_call_label"].setStyleSheet("QLabel{border:none;}")
            ip_call_item["gridLayout"].addWidget(ip_call_item["ip_call_label"], 0, 0, 1, 1)

            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"].setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 29))
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"].clicked.connect(lambda state,index=len(self.live_ip_calls):self.remove_ip_call(index))
            ip_call_item["gridLayout"].addWidget(ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"], 1, 0, 1, 1)

            ip_call_item["ip_call_label"].setText("Placeholder τηλεφωνικής κλήσης μέσω διαδικτύου όπου τα μη σταθερά στοιιχεία θα οριστούν μεταγενέστερα.")
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"].setText("Διαγραφή")


            self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            self.live_ip_calls.append(ip_call_item)
            
            self.resize_the_Dialog()
        except:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)
        

    def resize_the_Dialog(self):                
        self.ui.details_frame.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.ui.details_frame.setMaximumHeight(10*1000)
        
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setMaximumHeight(10*1000)
        self.Dialog.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.Dialog.setMaximumHeight(11*1000)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.ui.details_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        
    
        self.ui.details_frame.adjustSize()
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.adjustSize()
        self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        
        self.Dialog.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        details_frame_height = 9
        #details_frame_height = 0
        for ip_call in self.live_ip_calls:
            frame = ip_call["ip_call_frame"]
            frame_height = frame.sizeHint().height()
            details_frame_height += frame_height + 6
        if len(self.live_ip_calls)>0:
            details_frame_height -= 6
        details_frame_height += 9

        self.ui.details_frame.setFixedHeight(details_frame_height)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
        self.ui.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizeHint().height())

        
        self.Dialog.setFixedWidth(int(0.9*GetSystemMetrics(0)))

        #return None
        window_height_expanding = 0
        add_call_details_const_height = self.ui.add_call_details_const.height()
        add_call_details_dynamic_height = self.ui.add_call_details_dynamic.height()
        scrollArea_height = self.ui.scrollArea.height()
        frame_2_height = self.ui.frame_2.height()
        
        window_height_expanding = copy.deepcopy(int(11 + self.label_height + 6 + add_call_details_const_height + 6 + add_call_details_dynamic_height + 6 + scrollArea_height + 6 + frame_2_height + 11))
        self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_height_expanding)
        
        window_fixed_width = int(0.9*GetSystemMetrics(0))

        window_max_height = int(0.9*GetSystemMetrics(1))

        
        
        
        self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(1)
        window_height_2 = self.Dialog.frameSize().height()
        self.window_height_2 = window_height_2
        details_frame_height_max = abs(window_max_height - window_height_2 - 1) - 11 - 11 - self.label_height - 6 - add_call_details_const_height - 6 - add_call_details_dynamic_height - 6 - frame_2_height
        self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_height_expanding)
        #return None
        
            
        self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.ui.details_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.Dialog.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)     
        self.ui.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)       
        self.ui.details_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        if details_frame_height>details_frame_height_max:
            self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
            self.ui.details_frame.setFixedHeight(details_frame_height)
            self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
            self.ui.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height_max+9)
            scrollArea_height = 9+details_frame_height_max+9
            
        else:
            self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.ui.details_frame.setFixedHeight(details_frame_height)
            self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
            self.ui.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
            scrollArea_height = 9+details_frame_height+9
            
            
        window_height_expanding = 0
        add_call_details_const_height = self.ui.add_call_details_const.sizeHint().height()
        add_call_details_dynamic_height = self.ui.add_call_details_dynamic.sizeHint().height()
        scrollArea_height = self.ui.scrollArea.sizeHint().height()
        frame_2_height = self.ui.frame_2.sizeHint().height()
        
        window_height_expanding = 11 + self.label_height + 6 + add_call_details_const_height + 6 + add_call_details_dynamic_height + 6 + scrollArea_height + 6 + frame_2_height + 11

        
        #self.main_self.scheduled_transmitions_create_telephone_calls_window.adjustSize()
        if window_height_expanding>window_max_height:
            self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_max_height)
        else:
            self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_height_expanding)
        
        self.Dialog.setFixedWidth(window_fixed_width)
        #self.main_self.scheduled_transmitions_create_telephone_calls_window.update()

        
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog.timeout.connect(lambda widget=self.Dialog:self.center_the_QDialog(widget))
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog.start(200)
            
    def center_the_QDialog(self,widget,host=None):
        try:
            screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
            screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
            dw = self.app.desktop()
            taskbar_height = dw.screenGeometry().height() - dw.availableGeometry().height()
            taskbar_width = dw.screenGeometry().width() - dw.availableGeometry().width()
            if taskbar_height<100:
                available_screen_height = screen_height - taskbar_height
                available_screen_width = screen_width
            else:
                available_screen_height = screen_height
                available_screen_width = screen_width - taskbar_width
                
            qdialog_width = self.Dialog.frameSize().width()
            qdialog_height = self.Dialog.frameSize().height()
            
            x = (available_screen_width - qdialog_width) / 2
            y = (available_screen_height - qdialog_height) / 2
            width = self.Dialog.size().width()
            height = self.Dialog.size().height()
            self.Dialog.move(x,y)
            self.Dialog.setFixedWidth(width)
            self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(height)
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)
                
    #add_call_details dynamic click event
    def on_add_call_details_dynamic_click(self,state):
        try:
            ip_call_item = {}
            
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"] = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Dialog)
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
            "    border:1px solid #ABABAB;background-color:#EFEFEF;\n"
            "}")
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
            ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"].setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
            ip_call_item["gridLayout_3"] = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            ip_call_item["ip_call_label"] = QtWidgets.QLabel(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            ip_call_item["ip_call_label"].setStyleSheet("border:none;color:green;font-weight:bold;")
            ip_call_item["gridLayout_3"].addWidget(ip_call_item["ip_call_label"], 0, 0, 1, 1)
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"] = QtWidgets.QPushButton(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"].setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 29))
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"].clicked.connect(lambda state,index=len(self.live_ip_calls):self.remove_ip_call(index))
            ip_call_item["gridLayout_3"].addWidget(ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"], 1, 0, 1, 1)

            ip_call_item["ip_call_label"].setText("Placeholder τηλεφωνικής κλήσης μέσω διαδικτύου όπου τα μη σταθερά στοιιχεία θα οριστούν μεταγενέστερα.")
            ip_call_item["ip_call_delete"].setText("Διαγραφή")
            
            self.ui.verticalLayout.addWidget(ip_call_item["ip_call_frame"])
            self.live_ip_calls.append(ip_call_item)
            self.resize_the_Dialog()
        except:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)

    def remove_ip_call(self,index):
        try:
            self.ui.verticalLayout.removeWidget(self.live_ip_calls[index]["ip_call_frame"])
            self.live_ip_calls[index]["ip_call_frame"].deleteLater()
            self.live_ip_calls[index]["ip_call_frame"] = None

            del self.live_ip_calls[index]
            counter = -1
            for live_ip_call in self.live_ip_calls:
                counter += 1
                self.live_ip_calls[counter]["ip_call_delete"].clicked.disconnect()
                self.live_ip_calls[counter]["ip_call_delete"].clicked.connect(lambda state,index=counter:self.remove_ip_call(index))
            self.resize_the_Dialog()            
        except:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)
            
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        try:
            event.accept()          
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    programm = Run_me()
```

The window is resized, **but** i see this warnings in console:

```
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1525x191+197+412 (frame: 154
1x229+189+382) on QWidgetWindow/"DialogWindow" on "\\.\DISPLAY1". Resulting geom
etry: 1525x237+197+412 (frame: 1541x275+189+382) margins: 8, 30, 8, 8 minimum si
ze: 1525x191 maximum size: 1525x191 MINMAXINFO maxSize=0,0 maxpos=0,0 mintrack=1
541,229 maxtrack=1541,229)
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1525x423+197+412 (frame: 154
1x461+189+382) on QWidgetWindow/"DialogWindow" on "\\.\DISPLAY1". Resulting geom
etry: 1525x461+197+412 (frame: 1541x499+189+382) margins: 8, 30, 8, 8 minimum si
ze: 1525x423 maximum size: 1525x11000 MINMAXINFO maxSize=0,0 maxpos=0,0 mintrack
=1541,461 maxtrack=1541,11038)
QWindowsWindow::setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 1525x1+197+412 (frame: 1541x
39+189+382) on QWidgetWindow/"DialogWindow" on "\\.\DISPLAY1". Resulting geometr
y: 1525x461+197+412 (frame: 1541x499+189+382) margins: 8, 30, 8, 8 minimum size:
 1525x1 maximum size: 1525x1 MINMAXINFO maxSize=0,0 maxpos=0,0 mintrack=1541,39
maxtrack=1541,39)
...
```

Any error would happen, but i may know how can i solve this warnings.

Screenshot:

[image]

The resize method is called after the click on the first and the second buttons. So one ip_call_frame is added, the resize and the center methods are called.

Related links:

1. https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp
2. https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp?h=5.7

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and, *please*, really, use shorter and more readable object names.

Comment: I provide a reproducible example (is not as minimal as possible).

Comment: Then do more efforts and make it also minimal.

Comment: A lot of progress to be as small as possible.

Comment: @musicamante any progress? I found that setFixedHeight(1) not work at all times.

Comment: With all due respect, you've been here for years. You should already know how to make a *minimal and reproducible* example that respects the voluntary willingness to help others: without going into the depth of the >400 lines you provided, I can easily fast-scroll through your code and spot: function calls that are irrelevant to the problem, unnecessarily verbose namings or object declarations, terrible naming choices, and so on. You can do what you want with your own code, but we're here to help by providing our spare time for free. The least you *should* do is to make our work easy.

Comment: With the above I don't mean that I'm ignoring/underestimating your problem. But you're not putting us in a position that allows us to focus on the problem itself, as we will be constantly being distracted by confusing code that is difficult to read. We should focus on the problem, not on *interpreting* how the sources would cause it. Be also aware that this may also be a problem *for you* (and, IIRC, I've already pointed out this aspect to you previously): if you are distracted by *interpreting* the code, you'll have less resources to understand what it actually does. Even if it's *your* code.

Comment: Remember that programming is closely related to problem solving: you should focus on solving a problem. If the problem is difficult to understand, you also need to focus on solving the further problem of understanding the actual problem. If the *explanation* of the problem is difficult to understand, then you also need to focus on understanding what the actual problem is. All these layers of understanding add extreme difficulties to anybody (us, and you), reducing the available resources (in time and efforts) to solve the *real* problem. Be smart: *reduce* (and find) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if i use Ignored size policy then the warning is gone...

```py
    def resize_the_Dialog(self):                
        self.ui.details_frame.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.ui.details_frame.setMaximumHeight(10*1000)
        
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setMaximumHeight(10*1000)
        self.Dialog.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.Dialog.setMaximumHeight(11*1000)
        self.Dialog.setMaximumWidth(0)
        self.Dialog.setMaximumWidth(11*1000)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.ui.details_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        
        self.Dialog.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.ui.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        self.ui.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #self.ui.add_call_details_const.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        #self.ui.add_call_details_dynamic.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        #self.ui.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        #self.ui.frame_2.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
    
        self.ui.details_frame.adjustSize()
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.adjustSize()
        self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        

        details_frame_height = 9
        #details_frame_height = 0
        for ip_call in self.live_ip_calls:
            frame = ip_call["ip_call_frame"]
            frame_height = frame.sizeHint().height()
            details_frame_height += frame_height + 6
        if len(self.live_ip_calls)>0:
            details_frame_height -= 6
        details_frame_height += 9

        self.ui.details_frame.setFixedHeight(details_frame_height)
        self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
        self.ui.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)

        
        self.Dialog.setFixedWidth(int(0.9*GetSystemMetrics(0)))

        #return None
        window_height_expanding = 0
        add_call_details_const_height = self.ui.add_call_details_const.height()
        add_call_details_dynamic_height = self.ui.add_call_details_dynamic.height()
        scrollArea_height = self.ui.scrollArea.height()
        frame_2_height = self.ui.frame_2.height()
        
        window_height_expanding = copy.deepcopy(int(11 + self.label_height + 6 + add_call_details_const_height + 6 + add_call_details_dynamic_height + 6 + scrollArea_height + 6 + frame_2_height + 11))
        self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_height_expanding)
        
        window_fixed_width = int(0.9*GetSystemMetrics(0))

        window_max_height = int(0.9*GetSystemMetrics(1))
        
        
        
        #self.Dialog.setGeometry(1,1,1,1)

        self.Dialog.setMinimumHeight(1)
        self.Dialog.setMaximumHeight(1)
        self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(1)

        window_height_2 = self.Dialog.frameSize().height()
        self.Dialog.update()
        self.window_height_2 = window_height_2
        details_frame_height_max = abs(window_max_height - window_height_2 - 1) - 11 - 11 - self.label_height - 6 - add_call_details_const_height - 6 - add_call_details_dynamic_height - 6 - frame_2_height
        self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_height_expanding)
        
            
        self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        #self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        #self.ui.details_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        #self.Dialog.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)

        #self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)        
        #self.ui.scrollArea.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)        
        #self.ui.details_frame.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        if details_frame_height>details_frame_height_max:
            self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
            self.ui.details_frame.setFixedHeight(details_frame_height)
            self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
            self.ui.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height_max+9)
            scrollArea_height = 9+details_frame_height_max+9
            
        else:
            self.ui.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
            self.ui.details_frame.setFixedHeight(details_frame_height)
            self.ui.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
            self.ui.scrollArea.setFixedHeight(9+details_frame_height+9)
            scrollArea_height = 9+details_frame_height+9
            
            
        window_height_expanding = 0
        add_call_details_const_height = self.ui.add_call_details_const.sizeHint().height()
        add_call_details_dynamic_height = self.ui.add_call_details_dynamic.sizeHint().height()
        scrollArea_height = self.ui.scrollArea.height()
        frame_2_height = self.ui.frame_2.sizeHint().height()
        
        window_height_expanding = 11 + self.label_height + 6 + add_call_details_const_height + 6 + add_call_details_dynamic_height + 6 + scrollArea_height + 6 + frame_2_height + 11


        
        #self.main_self.scheduled_transmitions_create_telephone_calls_window.adjustSize()
        if window_height_expanding>window_max_height:
            self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_max_height)
        else:
            self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(window_height_expanding)
        
        self.Dialog.setFixedWidth(window_fixed_width)
        #self.main_self.scheduled_transmitions_create_telephone_calls_window.update()

        #self.Dialog.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        #self.ui.label.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog.timeout.connect(lambda widget=self.Dialog:self.center_the_QDialog(widget))
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer_for_center_the_QDialog.start(200)
            
    def center_the_QDialog(self,widget,host=None):
        try:
            screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
            screen_height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
            dw = self.app.desktop()
            taskbar_height = dw.screenGeometry().height() - dw.availableGeometry().height()
            taskbar_width = dw.screenGeometry().width() - dw.availableGeometry().width()
            if taskbar_height<100:
                available_screen_height = screen_height - taskbar_height
                available_screen_width = screen_width
            else:
                available_screen_height = screen_height
                available_screen_width = screen_width - taskbar_width
                
            qdialog_width = self.Dialog.frameSize().width()
            qdialog_height = self.Dialog.frameSize().height()
            
            x = (available_screen_width - qdialog_width) / 2
            y = (available_screen_height - qdialog_height) / 2
            width = self.Dialog.size().width()
            height = self.Dialog.size().height()
            self.Dialog.move(int(x),int(y))
            self.Dialog.setFixedWidth(width)
            self.Dialog.setFixedHeight(height)
        except Exception as e:
            error_message = str(traceback.format_exc())
            print(error_message)
```

If anyone understand this behavior please comment.